# best way to check for null and integer comparison using Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have 2 linked lists in scala with following node class definition:

```
class node(_x: Int = 0, nxt: node = null) {
    var x = _x
    var next = nxt
}
```

I want to merge two linked lists (which will be in ascending sort order) into a third sorted list. **What is the best way to do this in Scala.**

My solution:

```
object Solution {
    def mergeTwoLists(list1: node, list2: node): node = {
        (list1.x >= list2.x) match {
            case true => ListNode(list2.x, mergeTwoLists(list1, list2.next))
            case false => ListNode(list1.x, mergeTwoLists(list2, list1.next))
        }
    }
}
```

however, when I run this, I get nullPointerException for following 2 lists
[1,2,4]
[1,3,4]

Comment: Why not following the normal and simple ADT approach to define an immutable linked list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a `println((list1, list2))` at the start of your function, you'll see that at some point you're comparing `Node(4,null)` to `null`.

---

Before fixing it, your code is full of code smells and things that don't follow Scala best practices:

- In Scala, you shouldn't really ever get a NullPointerException because you should *never* intentionally use `null`. That's what Options are for.
- Use capital letters when defining classes (i.e. `Node` over `node`).
- Your class definition is far too Java-y and over-complicated. It can be simplified to `case class Node(x: Int = 0, next: Node = null)` (ignoring the incorrect use of `null`) without the private/public variable stuff.
- Your function has an unnecessary pattern match in it - nothing technically wrong with it, but it's a bit weird (note: subjective) to match on true/false instead of using an `if` statement.

So to re-write your (still broken) function, it would look more like this:

```scala
case class Node(x: Int = 0, next: Node = null)

def mergeTwoLists(list1: Node, list2: Node): Node = {
  if (list1.x >= list2.x) {
    Node(list2.x, mergeTwoLists(list1, list2.next))
  } else {
    Node(list1.x, mergeTwoLists(list2, list1.next))
  }
}

mergeTwoLists(Node(1, Node(2, Node(4))), Node(1, Node(3, Node(4))))
```

---

On to fixing it:

- Change the class definition to make the second parameter optional (to avoid `null`):

```scala
case class Node(x: Int = 0, next: Option[Node] = None)
```

- Change your function to make the second parameter optional to account for this:

```scala
def mergeTwoLists(list1: Node, list2: Option[Node]): Node = {
  ???
}
```

- You need to know if the second list is present or not. If it's None, just return the first list. Otherwise, carry on:

```scala
def mergeTwoLists(list1: Node, list2: Option[Node]): Node = {
  list2 match {
    case None => list1
    case Some(list) => ???
  }
}
```

- Finally, modify your original if/else to account for the new optional second parameter in the Node:

```scala
def mergeTwoLists(list1: Node, list2: Option[Node]): Node = {
  list2 match {
    case None => list1
    case Some(list) =>
      if (list1.x >= list.x) {
        Node(list.x, Some(mergeTwoLists(list1, list.next)))
      } else {
        Node(list1.x, Some(mergeTwoLists(list, list1.next)))
      }
  }
}
```

Now, if you pass in your inputs you'll get a more sensible output:

```scala
mergeTwoLists(
  Node(1, Some(Node(2, Some(Node(4))))),
  Some(Node(1, Some(Node(3, Some(Node(4))))))
)
```

outputs

```scala
Node(1,Some(Node(1,Some(Node(2,Some(Node(3,Some(Node(4,Some(Node(4,None)))))))))))
```

---

Note: I don't know if this is the "best" way but it's how to solve your problem with the function you've given already. I'd also consider renaming the variables as `list1`, `list2` and `list` are a bit confusing.

Scastie of it working: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tUPoVzKpRRSJjZz62KsmhQ